# Strange behavior with println and System.currentTimeMillis

Tags: scala

I run the following code:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis
      println("took " + (System.currentTimeMillis - start) + " ms")
    }
    {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis
      val took = System.currentTimeMillis - start
      println(s"took $took ms")
    }
  }
}
```

and it gives:

```
took 246 ms
took 0 ms
```

But if I swap two blocks, then I get

```
took 0 ms
took 0 ms
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to believe that you could measure anything meaningful in this way, so it's a bit like conjecturing about how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.

There are options for inspecting what your code compiles to:

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ skalac -Xprint:typer angeldance.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // angeldance.scala
package angeldance {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): angeldance.Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      {
        val start: Long = java.this.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
        scala.this.Predef.println("took ".+(java.this.lang.System.currentTimeMillis().-(start)).+(" ms"))
      };
      {
        val start: Long = java.this.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
        val took: Long = java.this.lang.System.currentTimeMillis().-(start);
        scala.this.Predef.println(scala.StringContext.apply("took ", " ms").s(took))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the second case, `StringContext.s` is using `java.lang.StringBuilder`, while the expression in the first case is using `scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder`.  That could induce a cost in class loading.  You'd have to be pretty curious about it to try `-XX:+PrintClassLoading`. Invoke it as `scala -J-XX:+PrintClassLoading`.

```
scala> val i = 5L
i: Long = 5

scala> "hello, " + i
res0: String = hello, 5

scala> :javap -
  Size 1007 bytes
  MD5 checksum bbccca3ecafe9287f07df81ea123676e
  Compiled from "<console>"
[snip]
         8: aload_0       
         9: new           #23                 // class scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder
        12: dup           
        13: invokespecial #24                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
        16: ldc           #26                 // String hello, 
        18: invokevirtual #30                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
        21: getstatic     #35                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
        24: invokevirtual #39                 // Method .i:()J
        27: invokestatic  #45                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToLong:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
        30: invokevirtual #30                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
        33: invokevirtual #48                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: Additional classloading looks like a correct answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's something with warming up of JVM (optimizaions on the run?), because when I try the code lower it gives me zero times (I added one `println` call).

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("x")
    val a = ()=> {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis
      println("took " + (System.currentTimeMillis - start) + " ms")
    }
    val b = ()=> {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis
      val took = System.currentTimeMillis - start
      println(s"took $took ms")
    }
    a()
    b()
  }
}
```

```
x
took 0 ms
took 0 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two advice:
1) Rather than using `System.currentTimeMillis`, use `System.nanoTime` to get more precision.
2) Find the average after calling the method many times (10x, 100x,..).

The reason seems to be your first block calls `System.currentTimeMillis` inside the println while the second block computes the value before.

Here's my result calling the method a few more times in the style of the second block (took is computed outside println), and using ns.

took 140 ns
took 119 ns
took 150 ns
took 132 ns
took 129 ns

Comment: I can replace 'currentTimeMillis' with 'nanoTime' myself and I know that putting the computation outside of println fixes the problem. I'm curious about the nature of such a behavior, not about how to "fix" it.